# Where can I find my space docker?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I had gotten the space car, and I saved it in Franklin's garage. Next, I saved the game and quit playing.

When I played the game today, the car isn't in either of Franklin's garages or the impound.

There was time when we would save a car under Franklin, and then it would end up in either Michaels or Trevor's garage or in impound, so we checked those as well.

We even tried going back to where we got it from and nothing! Is it gone forever or how do we get it back?

Comment: I have heard restarting the console may make the car re-appear at Franklin's Garage.

Comment: I totalled it accidentally driving off a cliff while going back to the garage to store it safely and haven't seen it since :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get it again, unless you start the game again with a different save or edit your save data with save data editors to add it to your garage.